# Projecting to wireless display using Powershell

Tags: wireless-networking, display, powershell

I am wondering if there is a way to enumerate available wireless displays using Powershell, retrieve metrics such as signal quality, and connect.

I am putting together a Windows 10 for iot device which should, supposedly, automatically connect to the closest, available and open wireless display, and start projecting to it, immediately after booting.

Comment: What research have you done so far? PowerShell is extensible, and hooks into WMI giving a pretty deep level of control. But right now, it sounds like you've come asking us to build a solution for you. If you've tried things already, let us know what they are and how they have failed so that we know what not to suggest.

Comment: Not asking anyone to "build a solution for me", merely asking for pointers on where to get started, since so far pure searching did not yield useful results.

Comment: Wireless displays are just Wifi or BT hotspots.   PowerShell notwithstanding, we all know that Windows automatically finds and lists all Wifi / BT hotspots that are broadcasting / discoverable by default. You cannot get metrics on anything you have not yet connected to. So, to determine the closest one, you'd have to connect to each and then extrapolate.